# sed swap words in a single command

Tags: bash, sed

How do I swap specific words with sed:
consider a single line of input (in my case it is a path):

```
foo/bar/TEST/foo/bar/...
```

there is parallel path:

```
foo/bar/PROD/foo/bar/...
```

I want to swap TEST and PROD depending on the original path

My first attempt was:

```
sed -e "s#TEST#PROD#g" -e "s#TEST#PROD/g"
```

but unfortunately:

```
echo "foo/bar/PROD/foo/bar/..." | sed -e "s#TEST#PROD#g" -e "s#PROD#TEST#g"
result: foo/bar/TEST/foo/bar/...
```

works as desired, but

```
echo "foo/bar/TEST/foo/bar/..." | sed -e "s#TEST#PROD#g" -e "s#PROD#TEST#g"
result: foo/bar/TEST/foo/bar/...
```

does not change anything or better does both substitions.

I'm looking for an option that the second substition is not performed when the first was successful.

Any ideas or is there a even better approach?

Comment: Maybe a better example would contain both TEST and PROD in the input, e.g. `echo 'foo/TEST/bar/PROD/foo' | sed '...'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the test operator for sed

```
sed 's#TEST#PROD#g;t;s#PROD#TEST#g' file
```

> **t label**
>                 If  a  s///  has  done a successful substitution since the last input line was read and since the last t or T command, then branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of
>                 script.

As there is no label then as mentioned in the extract from the man page it will branch to the end of the script, meaning no further commands are executed.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you want:

```
$ echo 'foo/TEST/bar/PROD/foo' |
    sed 's/TEST/\n/g; s/PROD/TEST/g; s/\n/PROD/g'
foo/PROD/bar/TEST/foo
```

Not all seds will support `\n` for a newline, though. Either of these will work in any sed:

```
$ echo 'foo/TEST/bar/PROD/foo' |
    sed 's/TEST/\
/g; s/PROD/TEST/g; s/\
/PROD/g'
foo/PROD/bar/TEST/foo

$ echo 'foo/TEST/bar/PROD/foo' |
    sed 's/a/aA/g; s/TEST/aB/g; s/PROD/TEST/g; s/aB/PROD/g; s/aA/a/g'
foo/PROD/bar/TEST/foo
```

with the latter having the "advantage" that it'd work even if you were crazy enough to be using seds hold space/buffer to contain multi-line content.